# how do I get my background to stretch the entire page

Tags: css

I know this has been asked I thought I was doing it correctly but it's only stretching the height of the content.

Here is my example:

[image]

My css is as follows:

```
body 
{   
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-size: .85em;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #4c89b6;

        background-image: url('../Content/images/tribackground.png');
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
        background-size: 1px 100%;

}
```

Any suggestions on how to get this to fill the page with the background?

======= UPDATE =======

I made the change to the following:

```
body 
{   
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-size: .85em;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #4c89b6;

  backgound-size: cover;
  background-image: url('../Content/images/tribackground.png');
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

I also tried:

```
body 
{   
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-size: .85em;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #4c89b6;

  background-size:100%;
  background-image: url('../Content/images/tribackground.png');
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

both did this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the image you included in your question it looks like you have an image that fades out as it goes up which you are only repeating across the bottom of the page. If this is not the case they the answers already given cover the question completely.

By default a background image will repeat both horizontally and vertically until it covers the entire background area. If you are wanting one image stretched across the entire space see the other answers. If you are wanting the image repeated in the horizontal across the bottom of the screen but not vertically then you will need to add:

```
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: bottom;
```

and remove the background-size: attribute. This will cause the image to stay at the bottom of the screen and text will scroll over it if the content extends off the bottom of the screen. If your content doesn't fill the entire screen the images will still be repeated across the bottom of the page.

If you remove the background-attachment: attribute then the image will repeat across the bottom of the content area rather that is part way up the screen or scrolled completely off the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 2):

in modern browsers you can use

```
backgound-size: cover;
```

A few different approches listed here:
http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

but the main problem here is that your body/html does not have min height of 100%. It would probably work if you just use:

```
body, html {
   min-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try that :

```
background-size: 100% auto; # width and height, can be %, px or whatever.
```

Answer (score 0):

background-size:100%;

your version (1px 100%) is restricting the height.